Create tag with arn for each resource of an AWS service
I created a Cloud Custodian policy file which ensures tag compliance over an AWS service. This works fine for static tag values, but I am struggling adding a tag value representing the arn of the affected AWS resource.
- name: xray-rule-tag-compliance
  resource: xray-rule
  filters:
    - or:
      - not:
        - "tag:ID": 12345678
      - not:
        - "tag:Resource Owner": me@example.org
      - not:
        - "tag:Technical Contact": you@example.org
      - not:
        - "tag:Account ID": 123456789012
      - not:
        - "tag:ARN": <arn of current AWS resource>

  actions:
    - type: tag
      tags:
        FACTS ID: f0d0d593db408014384ce6ab0b96196c
        Resource Owner: me@example.org
        Technical Contact: you@example.org
        Account ID: 470866575089
        ARN: <arn of current AWS resource>

Here is my policy.yml:
- name: xray-rule-tag-compliance
  resource: xray-rule
  filters:
    - or:
      - not:
        - "tag:ID": 12345678
      - not:
        - "tag:Resource Owner": me@example.org
      - not:
        - "tag:Technical Contact": you@example.org
      - not:
        - "tag:Account ID": 123456789012
      - not:
        - "tag:ARN": <arn of current AWS resource>

  actions:
    - type: tag
      tags:
        FACTS ID: f0d0d593db408014384ce6ab0b96196c
        Resource Owner: me@example.org
        Technical Contact: you@example.org
        Account ID: 123456789012
        ARN: <arn of current AWS resource>


Wouldn't this prevent anyone from ever creating any resources, since you never know the ARN of the resource until after it is created, so you can't set the ARN tag until after the resource is created? I also fail to see how this could be useful at all, since you already have the ability to reference the ARN directly on the resource, so why do you need to copy that value to a tag on the same resource?

The tag action should be applied to already existing resources if their tags do not match the values configured in the filters to match our company's compliance rules. The ARN tag should be contained in a tag based report for all AWS resources in a specific AWS service.
